# Nonlinear term with unknown in R

Tags: r, regression, gnm

I have a logistic regression using `glm` and I would like to add a term of the form

c<sub>1</sub>(k+ac<sub>2</sub>)/(t+c<sub>2</sub>)

where k and t are columns in a data frame, a is a constant. I would like R to find best-fit values for c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub>. Is this possible?

If I only wanted a fixed value, say c<sub>2</sub> = 2,

c<sub>1</sub>(k+2a)/(t+2)

I could just write

```
glm( model$y ~ I((model$k + 2*a)/(model$t + 2)) + model$otherterms,
  family = binomial(logit) )
```

which is similar to what I am doing now. But I don't think that 2 is optimal and iterating 'manually' is very time-consuming.

Comment: look at the function `nls`

Comment: @mnel: How can I tell it that two of the parameters are equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use function gnm from package **gnm**.

```
gnm(y~Mult(1, # c1
           offset(k)+1,# c3=a*c2 
           Inv(offset(t)+1)) # c2
           +other terms, 
    family=binomial, 
    data=models)
```

EDIT (solution for constrained coefficients)

```
term_fun <- function(predLabels, varLabels){
                     paste0(predLabels[1],"*(",varLabels[1],
                            "+",predLabels[2],"*3)/(", # a=3 for example
                            varLabels[2],"+", predLabels[3],")")}

  Ratio <- function(t,x){
   list(predictors = list(C1 = 1, C2 = 1),
        variables = list(substitute(t), substitute(x)),
        term = term_fun)
  }
  class(Ratio) <- "nonlin"

  fit <- gnm(Y~Ratio(k,t), data=models, family=binomial)
```

Comment: How can I constrain c3 = a*c2 for a given value of a? For example, suppose a = 0.4.

Comment: In other words, the second and third constants aren't independent and need to be fixed multiples of each other; how can I achieve this?

Comment: I have added solution for constrained c3=a*c2.

Comment: That is awesome and complicated. Thank you, I don't think I ever would have come up with that.